# Edit and display entity images

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I want to be able to replace my old images with a new. I got one to many relationship between entites -> many images for one product.

If I change images, old are staying in database. They will be never used. After some time the database is able to make huge itself. How to delete these old files ?

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
        { return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest); }

    Product product = db.Products.Include(p => p.FilePaths).Where(i => i.ProductId == id).Single();    
    if (product == null)
        { return HttpNotFound(); }

    return View(product);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> uploads)
{
    var product = db.Products.Include(p => p.FilePaths).Where(p => p.ProductId == id).Single();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            product.FilePaths = new List<FilePath>();

            foreach (var upload in uploads)
            {
                if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var photo = new FilePath
                    {
                        FileName = Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName),
                        FileType = FileType.Photo
                    };
                    product.FilePaths.Add(photo);
                    upload.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images"), photo.FileName));
                }
            }

            db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (RetryLimitExceededException)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Contact with administrator.");
        }
    }
    return View(product);
}
```

My view for Edit() is:

```
@model Domain.Entities.Product
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {

// code ommited for brevity..
<div class="row">
    @Html.Label("Images:", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <input type="file" name="uploads" id="upload1" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-1">
        <input type="file" name="uploads" id="upload2" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-1">
        <input type="file" name="uploads" id="upload3" />
    </div>
</div>
//code ommited for brevity..
```

**Also if somebody could tell me how to change this properly I would be grateful.**

I am getting first image of product as many times as many images a product got. I want to display all images once.
I am in trouble with a directory to images.

```
<div class="row">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2"> Obecne zdjęcia:</label>
    @foreach (var item in Model.FilePaths)
    {
        <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-1">
            <img src="~/Content/Images/@Model.FilePaths.FirstOrDefault(f => f.FileType == FileType.Photo).FileName" alt="" style="width:auto; height:100px">
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

My model class for FilePath:

```
public class FilePath
{
    public int FilePathId { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public FileType FileType { get; set; }

    public int? ProductId { get; set; }

    //navigation..
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Every help much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your model class? It's an issue with your model. Just make your foreign key a nullable field I believe.

Comment: Thank you Kala J. I'm not getting error actually. Unfortunately I'm still in trouble. After edit one of my products I'm loosing my images and staying with first one (this one I can edit properly). I want to be able to edit actual images and add some, too.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer regarding to image uploading on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651531/how-to-display-images-in-mvc) page.