# FormData Values in Razor HTML page, getting in C# Method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have following input element in razor view page

```
<input type="file" id="uploadFile" name="FileUpload" multiple="multiple" />
```

using following script I'm binding data to this ForData

```
$('#uploadFile').on('change', function()
{

  var fd = new FormData();
  var files = $('#uploadFile')[0].files;


  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) 
  {
    if (files[i].size < 5242880) 
    {       
       fd.append("myFiles", files[i])
    }
  }  
});
```

I'm trying to get these files in C# method like following

```
[HttpPost]        
public ActionResult SomeAction(ModelClass model)
{
    var attchaedfiles = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["myFiles"];

                for (int i = 0; i < attchaedfiles.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attchaedfiles[i].FileName))
                    {
                      ....
                    }
                }
}
```

but here I'm getting folllowing errors

> Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'method
>   group'
>
> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type
>   'System.Web.HttpPostedFile'

Comment: Put a `List<HttpPostedFileBase> myFiles` parameter in the method and use `for (int i = 0; i < myFiles.Count; i++)` - or better have a property for it in your model and simply upload the model including the files as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681)

Comment: youre saying soming like this `List<HttpPostedFileBase> myFiles = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["myFiles"];`

Comment: No. Just add the parameter - it will be bound with the files

Comment: in html append like following `fd.append("myFiles", files[i]);` added to method like following,   `public ActionResult SomeAction(ModelClass model, List<HttpPostedFileBase> myFiles)` but i can see values getting null :(

Comment: Then probably your ajax code is wrong (but you have not shown that).

Comment: i'm not binding these in ajax code, only within the  `$('#uploadFile').on('change', function()`

Comment: What? You have to use ajax to post `FormData`! If you not using ajax, then just make the parameter `List<HttpPostedFileBase> FileUpload` to match the name of the form control and delete your scripts (they are pointless)

Comment: I just want to filter `$('#uploadFile')[0].files;` and insert validated files to Array or Formdata, then access those in C# method, how can I do this properly ?

Comment: Exactly as per my last message - `FormData` is a special object used when posting data using ajax.

Comment: how can I bind values to `List<HttpPostedFileBase> FileUpload` from script ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136601/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-kez).

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax script, make sure you include these:

```
$.ajax({
    url: yourUrl,
    type: 'POST',
    // Needed for FormData submit
    processData: false,
    // Needed for FormData submit
    contentType: false,
    data: fd,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function () {
        // Success things
    },
    error: function () {
        // Error things
    },
    complete: function () {
        // Complete things
    }
});
```

And that your form code includes enctype = "multipart/form-data":

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { @action = YourAction, id = "your_id", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach that checks possible conditions regarding to file uploads:

***Model:***

```
public class ExperimentViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> FileUpload { get; set; }
    
    //other properties
}
```

***Controller:***

```
if (model.FileUpload != null)
{
    if (model.FileUpload.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (var upload in model.FileUpload)
        {
            if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                //your stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also look at my answer on [How to display images in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651531/how-to-display-images-in-mvc/30653266#30653266).